# working properly..but not showing error message when there is no feild for listing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

its working...but no showing error message in session ..when result is null ,it is executing like result is not null and not showing any result and error message..its working when provide session to if condition when data >0 ..its working on if condition when result is null...else condition is not working..but there is no result if is working..actually else condition with error message session have to work

controller

```
public function doctor_deptrlist_view($offset = 0)
{
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/User/doctor_deptrlist_view/";
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->User_model->deptr_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['h'] = $this->User_model->get_all_deptrdoctor($config['per_page'], $offset);

    if($data['h'] ){

        $this->load->view('customer/header');
        $this->load->view('customer/docer', $data);
        $this->load->view('customer/footer');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('customer/header');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! No Results available for your search!!!!</div>');
        $this->load->view('customer/docer');
        $this->load->view('customer/footer'); 

    }
}
```

model

```
public function deptr_count()
{

    $this->db->select('*');    
    $this->db->from('tbl_doctor');
    $this->db->join('tbl_specialisation', 'tbl_doctor.spec_id = tbl_specialisation.spec_id');

    $this->db->where("place LIKE 'Trivandrum'");
    $this->db->where("spec_specialise LIKE 'Nephrology'");

    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();

}

public function get_all_deptrdoctor($limit, $offset)  
{  

    //data is retrive from this query  
    $this->db->select('tbl_doctor.id,tbl_doctor.dr_name,
                       tbl_doctor.dr_img,tbl_specialisation.spec_specialise,
                       tbl_doctor.place,tbl_doctor.qualification');  
    $this->db->join('tbl_specialisation', 'tbl_doctor.spec_id = tbl_specialisation.spec_id');


    $this->db->where("place LIKE 'Trivandrum'");
    $this->db->where("spec_specialise LIKE 'Nephrology'");

    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_doctor',$limit, $offset);
    //var_dump($query); die();
    return $query;  
}
```

view

```
<div class="list "><div></div>
<ul>


<?php 
if(isset($h)):  
    foreach ($h->result() as $row): 
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/>
<li><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?><div class="imgt"><img src="<?php echo base_url("./resources/images/");  if($row->dr_img) echo $row->dr_img; else echo "no-img.jpg"; ?>" height="90px" width="82px"></div><div class="text"><h3><b>Dr. <?php echo  $row->dr_name;?></b><br></h3><p><?php echo  $row->spec_specialise;?><br><?php echo  $row->place;?><br><?php echo  $row->qualification;?></p></div><div class="text"></div><div class="link"><a href="<?php echo site_url('User/view_doctor/'.$row->id); ?>"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye sym"></i>View</a></div></li>

<?php 
    endforeach; 
else: echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'>Oops! No Results available for your search!!!</div>";
endif;
?>

<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?>

</ul>
<div class="space">
</div>
</div></div>
<div class="pdt_rightt">
<center>
<?php
   echo $this->pagination->create_links();
?>
```

Comment: Some simple sensible code indentation helps us read the code and more importantly helps **you debug the code**

Comment: I would start by thinking of a more reliable test than `if($data['h'] ){` My guess even when nothing is returned `$data['h']` has something in it

Comment: can you add session library?

Comment: yepp..session is working when it is replaced to if condition..but not in else